# Cannot convert Binding<Type> to Binding<Protocol>

Tags: swift, swiftui

`Cannot convert Binding<Type> to Binding<Protocol>` is the specific error message, but the underlying question is: What's a good architecture for holding a reference, then mutating & reading from the underlying object?

Examples:

- In an RPG, your character has a *currentArmor*. You want it to take damage.
- In Pokemon, you track a *currentPokemon*. It needs to level up.
- In Instagram, you have a *selectedPost*, you want the like button to mutate the underlying post.

Here's a concrete example showing what I tried: This app has several `Animal`s. You can use the app to edit the `currentAnimal`'s `name`.

**The error** `Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Dog>' to type 'Binding<Animal>'`:

```
protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get set }
}

struct Cow: Animal {
    var name: String
}

struct Dog: Animal {
    var name: String
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dog: Dog = Dog(name: "dog 1")
    // ** THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART ** //
    @Published var currentAnimal: Binding<Animal> = .constant(Cow(name: "cow 1"))
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.dog.name) // Show the underlying Dog
        }
            .onAppear {
                model.currentAnimal = $model.dog // Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Dog>' to type 'Binding<Animal>'
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                model.currentAnimal.wrappedValue.name = "dog 2" // Mutate state here
            }
    }
}
```

Yes, I'm aware of https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652064 But I don't think doing a force `as!` case is a good idea. Is there some way that generics instead of protocols could solve this problem? Or class inheritance instead of protocols? Or some other architecture?

Comment: Did you try this ? ```model.currentAnimal = .constant(model.dog)```

Comment: @RajaKishan Hmm.. yeah seems like that fixes swapping the `currentAnimal` back and forth, but now there's no way to edit the underlying `Animal` (fixed one problem, created another)

Comment: if you change both dog and cow struct to class and manually refresh the view by ```model.objectWillChange.send()```  then it will work. But I'm not sure it's good or bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: With Classes it works:

```
protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get set }
}

class Cow: Animal {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dog: Dog = Dog(name: "dog 1")
    // ** THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART ** //
    @Published var currentAnimal: Animal = Cow(name: "cow 1")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.dog.name) // Show the underlying Dog
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.currentAnimal = model.dog // Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Dog>' to type 'Binding<Animal>'
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            model.currentAnimal.name = "dog 2" // Mutate state here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't work because you changed `Text(model.dog.name)` to `Text(model.currentAnimal.name)`. You're just editing a _copy_ of dog now instead of the original dog object. Makes me wonder if this kind of thing's only possible with classes..

Comment: I still try to understand your goal ... you have different animals, each of them can become the currentAnimal. And by using currentAnimal you want to change the value of the underlying animal. But each animal (cow, dog) only exists once .. correct?

Comment: Nice clean solution. Thanks!